# List with multiple content types & forms

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, infopath, content-type, forms-services

I have a list with three content types. Each content type has its own forms.

```
Content Type A (Default Content Type)
Content Type B
Content Type C
```

My issue is that if I try to open the Edit form from within the Display form for `Content Type B` or `Content Type C`, instead of it using its respective form it tries to use the edit form for `Content Type A`. I have verified in SPD that each content type is pointing to its correct forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing this by restoring from a backup before the issue occurred.

Answer (score 0):

I would first check the content type definitions through the list settings to ensure that they have the correctly assigned columns for each content type. Are content type B and C children of content type A?

Comment: All appropriate columns are assigned to each content type. `Content Type B` & `Content Type C` are not children of `Content Type A`.